# gwt redeploy or update static files

Tags: gwt, properties

For accessing the database I created a database.properties file which contains username, password and so on for accessing the database. Now I had to change the password and I also changed that password in the database.properties file. However when running the GWT app in hosted mode it still uses the old file and the old password so the file is not actually updated although I reinitialized the app several times and also reloaded the page from within the browser the database.properties file does not get updated.

Any idea what I have to do?

Comment: Did you use the "reload the server" button of DevMode?

Comment: Yeah, it has no effect. The property file is not touched.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had an error in my setup which was due to my fault. Thanks for reading anyway.